# Do I need to reply to a moderator message?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderator-messages

I recently received a message from a moderator for my "bad" reviewing queues (yes, I'm guilty of this), but is it compulsory to message back? Or does it seem slightly rude to ignore their message, but still understand what they are trying to say?

Comment: No @bad_coder, that's one whether the moderate responds and stuff, this question is *slightly* different

Comment: MadScientist's answer under the linked post seems to address your question directly.

Comment: Other info:  There's often [no reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240149/282094), you are [writing to *anonymous*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283910/282094), and (last paragraph): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336550/282094 or use Contact Link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257612/282094

Comment: In meta, when there is answer that answers a different question, that different question might be closed as duplicate of the answer's question, **even when the questions are different**. This appears weird, I agree,  but that's the policy we currently have in place. It's not a rule set in stone of course, but pretty commonly used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need. You are not required to reply to a mod message unless there is something you want to clarify, something that needs to be clarified on their end or something that was done that you think shouldn't have.

Just take note of the message and avoid repeating the same mistake. That's a reply in itself :)

Comment: Currently there is no way to acknowledge (i.e. mark as "I have read it") a moderator message, but this can be a good feature request. This way the mods would know for sure when the user actually read their message.

Comment: Am I allowed to make a question on that? Or do we just leave it as a comment here?

Comment: If a moderator cares, they can check whether you have read a mod message. We do not need you to mark it as read - we need you to understand it and act on it.

Comment: @Nij how can a moderator check whether you have read a mod message or not? You mean directly ask the user?

Comment: yes, @DialFrost, if you feel like it is a good idea, no one's going to stop you from making a [tag:feature-request].

Comment: There is literally a statement saying so, "read D Mmm Yyyy H:mm". There is no need to say you've read it - we know whether you did or not. @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar

Comment: @Nij didn't know that, but still, it's more like "viewed [time here]", can't know if the user actually read and understood the message.

Comment: They opened the page and had the information available. Can't help, but don't care, if a user takes no heed of an individual message sent to them directly (for which there is nothing else even similar on the network).