# "I have read your message" moderator message

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderation

This feature request is regarding [this question on the response to moderator's message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378681/do-i-need-to-reply-to-a-moderator-message/378682):

- Add a small message box for the user to either tick or type a quick message back to acknowledge the moderator's message on the message and let the moderator know that the user has read and understood their message

Note that opening the page does not mean users have *read the message*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no need. Moderators already can see when you've read your message in the mod-message UI. It looks something like this:

[image]

Anything else would just add noise, so it's better to stick with the existing functionality.

Comment: Not really. One can click the link to the message, but never actually read it. This isn't very reliable. And users who actually send response like "OK, got it" making the actual "noise" as they have no way to know the moderator can see they viewed the private message.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar One can click a button, but never actually read the message either. Or write a response, you'd be surprised what we get sometimes...And yes, that's why I'm not suggesting to just type something like Glorfindel. The option to type (that the post asks for) is already there too, but using it for that would is just noise. Best way to show you've read a message and understood is to act accordingly. Not to press a button or send an 'okay, got it' reply

Comment: Well, technically I envision this as checkbox with caption like "I have read and acknowledged the message", not a button. Like the checkbox you get when installing programs. But you have a point, even if one would tick that, we can't know they actually read or understood anything, however chances they did are still better.

Answer (score 9):

♦ moderators can already see if (and when) the user first read the message. The messages are written in such a way that we expect them to be read and understood, and there will be consequences if not (and the behaviour continues).

And it's always fine to respond with something like "OK, I understand" or just "Thanks" - there's no character limit or such.

Comment: Opening a page does not mean the content of that page is read

Comment: Well that's the users fault really. I don't feel we have to cater to that. If they forget about it thats their own problem.

Comment: @Luuklag I don't really think an acknowledgement is useful. But wanted to put a reminder since there is an indicator that the message is "read" the system is most likely not reading the mind of the user and thus the information is inaccurate.

Comment: It's accurate, say, 95% of the time. The other 5% are exceptions, and moderators are supposed to be exception handlers :P